# Can I say "something in discussion" to refer to the thing being discussed?

Tags: prepositions

> The paragraph **under consideration** has nothing to do with his moral integrity.

The context is about how to understand a specific paragraph  in an article about a rich man.
Can I use “the paragraph **in** discussion" or "**under** discussion” to replace “under  consideration”?

Can I say "something **in** discussion" to refer to the thing being discussed?

Comment: Yes, both are acceptable. https://www.google.com/#q=%22matter+in+discussion%22+%22matter+under+discussion%22

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the consideration in question *is* a discussion, yes you can use "under discussion" as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider *the paragraph in question* or *the paragraph under examination* or many other similar variations.

Comment: That's not the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

[Below is the excerpt, in discussion.](http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-485891)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the idiom "in question".

Eg. *Besides the **person in question**, there were many other witnesses to the incident*.